# Import users from old WP site to new one

Tags: database, users, import, export

I want to import existing users with their passwords from an old WordPress site to a new one. The new WordPress installation has also existing users. Therefore I couldn't simply export/import the database tables from the old site.

Is there any other way to import the old users with passwords to the new site?

Comment: As long as you turn off the "create tables" option you can indeed export and import, and this will preserve both your new-site users and your old-site users on the new site. I would first take a backup of both sites, just in case.

Comment: and what happens if they have the same id's?

Comment: I'd expect them to be skipped. You would need to manually change IDs. There may also be a plugin available for this type of migration - I'd check for that first as preferable to rolling your own solution.

Comment: thanks for your comment. but there are to many IDs to change. And I also don't know what to do with the field "umeta_id". This is auto-generated and I don't know if and how I should change that. Unfortunately I couldn't find any plugin to do the job (with importing the passwords too).

Comment: `umeta_id` is a random number. As long as you don't have duplicate `umeta_id`s you can leave it alone. The other columns reference which user the meta belongs to, so it's completely arbitrary.

Comment: thanks!! do you have any idea how to set all the IDs and the umeta_id up by 100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the user `ID`s could be problematic. Other tables reference those - including `wp_usermeta` but if they are authors, customers, etc. then any tables that hold those items - like `wp_posts` - reference the author by user `ID`.

Changing the `umeta_id`s should be safe, because that value isn't referenced elsewhere that I'm aware of. It wouldn't hurt to check your particular plugins and other tables to see if they are indeed referenced somewhere.

It would be safest to use a plugin to migrate the users. It does appear that you'll have to have your old users reset their passwords, but that's a smaller price to pay than getting customers, authors, etc. all confused.

A couple of possible options: [Importing Users into new WordPress site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205559/importing-users-into-new-wordpress-site) and [importing users where password is provided as md5 + much metadata](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6118/importing-users-where-password-is-provided-as-md5-much-metadata).

Comment: thanks, i will do it this way and let the users set new passwords

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with this simple [WordPress user import export plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/users-customers-import-export-for-wp-woocommerce/), can migrate your password as well